How to Generate Static Pages in Next.js after build for Large E-commerce Sites?
I have developed an e-commerce website using Next.js with page routing and Laravel as the API backend. The site currently hosts around 10,000 products, and I need all product pages to be statically generated. One approach I'm considering is using Incremental Static Regeneration (ISR). However, due to the nature of my self-hosted Next.js setup, every time the Docker container restarts or the application is redeployed, all pre-built pages are purged. This results in users encountering pages that have not been pre-generated.
Another option is to generate all pages during the build process, but this is impractical due to the extensive time required.
I believe it would be beneficial if I could somehow generate static version of pages in a queue after each build, gradually completing all static pages over several hours.
Also, I have to say that each page will revalidate after any update by calling a webhook by backend.(On demand revalidation)
Is there a recommended approach or tooling to achieve this kind of static generation in Next.js, given the constraints of a self-hosted setup?
Thank you for any guidance or suggestions you can provide.

what next.js version are you using?

Another option is to generate all pages during the build process, but this is impractical due to the extensive time required.
if you have too many products, you prerender only the most popular ones, and store them in CDN. Or if it is a holiday season, let's say Christmas time, you also prerender related products
I believe it would be beneficial if I could somehow generate static version of pages in a queue after each build, gradually completing all static pages over several hours.
this is a good method if each page loading time takes long time. if a user visiting a product page which takes less time load, just prebuilt during the request. adding queue system in your backup will add extra complexity to the backend. you have to deal with bandwith usage, queue management, error handling.
If new products or updates to existing products might not be available immediately on the site until they are processed through the queue, this could be a significant issue if timely content updates are critical for your business.
you also have to monitor and maintaint the queue. you have to handle server downtime, managing queue backlogs, and updating the system to handle new page templates
